# Silverlight 3 - PlatformKeyCode for Comma on MAC

Tags: silverlight, macos

Can someone help me with the platformKeyCode for comma and decimal (but tot the one from Num Lock) on MAC?

I read here the reasons why the comma and the decimal point are not in the Keys enum from System.Windows.Input.Key, but I will need them for standard keyboards.
http://blogs.msdn.com/nickkramer/archive/2009/01/23/why-is-the-silverlight-key-enum-missing-common-characters-like-comma-and-period.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Mac PlatformKeyCode

```
Comma = 43
Period = 47
```

Windows PlatformKeyCode

```
Comma = 188
Period = 190
```